# Swing/Java: How to use the getText and setText string properly

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, settext

I'm trying to make input `nameField` appear in a `Label` called `label1` after a `Button` called `button1` is clicked.
Right now it says: 'txt' and I understand why. But I don't know how I can use the string!
Can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong and how to use this string properly?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class thisismytest2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();  
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();    
        JTextField nameField = new JTextField("...", 2);    
        JButton button1 = new JButton();
        final JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
        label1.setText("txt");
        label1.setVisible(false);
        String txt = nameField.getText();

        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(label1);
        frame.setSize(200,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        panel.add(nameField);
        frame.setSize(600,400); 
        nameField.setBounds(400, 40, 400, 30);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                label1.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        }
        }
```

Comment: You just retrieved the initial text of your nameField textfield, and your txt variable won't be updated automatically since there is no binding between that variable and the text property of the textfield, which is why you need to update the txt variable in the actionPerformed method, as the answers point out. If you're interested (later on) in being able to bind elements together (much more powerful approach), then know that there are libraries to do that such as: http://java.net/projects/beansbinding/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I appreciate it and take a good look at it

Comment: How do you get the name of a JButton so that you can check it in an IF statement???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are setting the label text before the button is clicked to "txt".  Instead when the button is clicked call `setText()` on the label and pass it the text from the text field.

Example:

```
label1.setText(nameField.getText());
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, and then i can remove setText from the row above?

Comment: yes you dont need it there unless you want it to have a default text.

Comment: So i don't even need String txt = nameField.getText ? :o

Comment: @Opoe, you only need to save the text into a String variable if you intend on using it elsewhere.

Comment: okay thanks, the error says the nameField has to be declared final. Do i have to add final before JTextField?

Comment: Sorry i got it :) Thank you so much for your time and help appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

in your action performed method, call:

```
label1.setText(nameField.getText());
```

This way, when the button is clicked, label will be updated to the nameField text.

Answer (score 2):

the `getText` method returns a String, while the `setText` receives a String, so you can write it like `label1.setText(nameField.getText());` in your listener.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a DocumentListener on nameField. When nameField is updated, update your label.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html

Comment: this link is to an old version of Java.